# Server DNS Resolve issue

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, reverse-dns

So I'm currently using VMware Pro 12 for the purpose of a lab environment. The problem I have now is that on my domain controller I can't ping my client, although the client is configured properly.

As a network adapter I use bridge mode.

The IPs are the following:

hostname: server01
domain: contoso.com
IP: 192.168.1.115
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 192.168.1.115

the client:

IP: 192.168.1.138
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 192.168.1.115

Although I managed to join the domain after long troubleshooting and DNS resolve problems, on the server site I still can't ping the address from the client.

I have some experience with server 2012 but I wanted to build my own lab environment with Server 2012 R2. I'm not quite sure where I could find the error what's causing this problem....

Comment: Is your problem with ICMP or DNS? you mention both ping and DNS in your question. They are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use NAT instead of bridge.  I used Bridge for connecting physical desktop to laptop by using Switch in between.

(2) By default VMWare has built-in DHCP Server.  Disable it, since it may interfere with DHCP Server configured in Windows Server.

Anyone could be the root cause of issue.